# Stop PHP from running if a GET variable doesn't exist

Tags: php, html

On my page, the user has a choice of what data to display. I did this simply using a dropdown list and GET parameters. It currently looks like this:

The form:

```
<form method="get" action="contents.php">
  <select name="TutorialBlock">
    <option value="tuts1">Block One - Starting</option>
    <option value="tuts2">Block Two</option>
    <option value="tuts3">Block Three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The script that loads the data depending what option the user chose:

```
<?php
  $var_value = $_GET['TutorialBlock'];
 include '/includes/'.$var_value.'.php';
?>
```

This works fine, and PHP includes the correct file depending on what option the user chose, the issue is, if the user hasn't chosen an option, PHP just throws up file not found errors, since it is looking for a file which isn't there. Is there a way that I can stop the PHP script from running if the GET parameter is not set?

Comment: Yes... `if(!isset($_GET['TutorialBlock'])) die('Parameter not found...');`

Comment: **Warning:** Including files based on a parameter users pass in is a potentially serious [directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).  This code is dangerous.

Comment: @dimo414 There are more serious vulnerabilities here. I.e. directory traversal/inclusion, LFI, etc.

Comment: No, it wouldn't pose an XSS vulnerability. He is vulnerable to a directory traversal attack.

Comment: Apologies, you're right, jumped on the wrong term.

Comment: However, this code would probably indicate other vulnerable code leading to a XSS attack.

Comment: Thanks to Darren, my code is now much more safe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing now is causing some serious vulnerabilities. You can never trust user input.

You should be running your `$_GET['TutorialBlock']` against a whitelist. Here is an example for you.

```
$whitelist = array(
    'page',
    'blockpage',
    //....etc
);

if(isset($_GET['TutorialBlock']) && !empty($_GET['TutorialBlock'])) {
    // now make sure it's in the whitelist.
    if(!in_array($_GET['TutorialBlock'], $whitelist)) {
        die('bad page');
    } else {
        include '/includes/'.$_GET['TutorialBlock'].'.php';
    }
} else {
     // user didn't select page... do something here..
}
```

<sup>*The above is only pseudo code (example), you still need to ensure user input is vaid.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I tried using this though, and I put the three variables in the whitelist (tuts1, tuts2 and tuts3) but it's giving me "bad page".

Am I actually doing this right?

Comment: @user3779981 how are you accessing `$_GET['TutorialBlock']` ? (*and there was a typo in the code above, I had `$__GET` instead of `$_GET` so if you copy/pasted it wouldn't have worked. Try now.*)

Comment: Ah yes, I copied & pasted, just noticed the error and fixed it in my code :)

Also, I'm a PHP newbie, obviously. What do you mean by how am I accessing it? It's literally just, user chooses the option, and then it's put into the address bar after it reloads the page and the PHP code will include a file :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var_value = isset($_GET['TutorialBlock']) ? $_GET['TutorialBlock'] : false;

if($var_value) {
  include '/includes/'.$var_value.'.php';
} else {
  // query value wasn't there
  exit("TutorialBlock is required");
}
```

**Important**

You're vulnerable to directory traversal attacks with your code as is.

Comment: This doesn't actually follow the brief: "is there a way that I can **stop the PHP script from running** if no GET variable is there?"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['TutorialBlock'])) {
    $var_value = $_GET['TutorialBlock'];
    include '/includes/'.$var_value.'.php';
} else {
    //not set
}
```

Comment: @user3779981 most definitely not perfect... try using `?TutorialBlock=someNonFileName`

Comment: Well, it seemed to do the job. What I meant, is when a user goes to the page for the first time, no GET variable would be set, so PHP would throw up errors.